# How to debugg/log firebase messaging topic sync result? on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app where I need to subscribe to several topics when the app gets destroyed.
I used the appdelegates method `applicationWillTerminate` to call `.subscribe(toTopic:xxx)` and log a message to confirm that the method got called.
I have a background mode active, so the method gets called only when the app is destroyed, and works as intended.
However, I cannot see a any logs from firebase that the topic sync succeeded or not.

I assume it didn't succeed because I'm not receiving any push notifications and because if I do `subscribe` to the same topicswhen the app starts, I receive all the notifications correctly.

I read that when the app gets destroyed, I have 5 seconds from generous  apple's iOS to complete the tasks I need. This amount of time should be more than enough to sync all the topics, however I can't find any logs to debug.

I looked through the logs available in the devices and simulators window, but didn't find anything, not event the message i printed inside the `applicationWillTermiate` method.

I know that on android, a topic sync will log the message `topic sync succesfull`, but what about iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Well have you checked the documentation?

> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. **For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called** when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

So if you have enabled background execution this is most likely not called, unless the system needs to terminate your app

As for the correct subscription, I guess you can check the Firebase console and see if the topic exists in the Compose message, although be advised it can take a few hours before the topic appears on the console it self.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did read the docs, and the docs say that the method will not be called `when the user quits the app` (as in minimised). It DOES get called when the app is swiped away(destroyed), and I can see the log message I put inside applicationWillTerminate method. My problem is with logging topic sync result from firebase's messaging api. The topics exist, as they are not defined by the user. To put it in a simple way, if I subscribe in applicationDidFinishLaunching, I receive the notifications, if I subscribe to the same topic in applicationWillTerminate, I don't receive them.